# Can't connect Office365 to Laravel mail

Tags: laravel, smtp, office365

I connected **Office365** account to laravel smtp mailer. But when I want to send mail I get exception:

> *Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP. For more information please go to
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=526653 AS(8561)*

I also added my server IP to *Admin->Protected->Connection filter->Allowed IP list.*

My .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=username
MAIL_FROM_NAME=MyOffice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [link in your question](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/email-non-delivery-reports-in-office-365-51daa6b9-2e35-49c4-a0c9-df85bf8533c3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

> **5.7.700-749 : Access denied, tenant has exceeded threshold**
>
> The majority of traffic from this tenant has been detected as suspicious and has resulted in a ban on sending ability for the tenant.
>
> Ensure that any compromises or open relays have been resolved, and then contact support through your regular channel.

Your tenant/subscription has been flagged for suspicious SMTP traffic. You need to contact Microsoft Support directly to correct the issue and remove the SMTP block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you give me a link where i can contact with microsoft support. System of office365 is complicated. I can't find something like support chat.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this Mail-Driver:
https://github.com/motze92/office365-mail

With SMTP and office365 we had many timeout problems and  temporarely errors. Sending mails over graph rest api works better.